# gem install rails does not install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I tries to install rails:

```
root@li44-48:/# gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.2.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.1...
```

But when I do:

```
root@li44-48:/# rails
-bash: rails: command not found
```

I checked `gem env` and it displays:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Also the folder `root@li44-48:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.2.1#` is empty.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an effort of rage quit, I:

1. removed ruby
2. removed gem

and recompiled both from source, and now `gem install rails` is fully working again.

Comment: select your answer as accepted. since this is unlikely to really help anyone out in the future you could even vote to have the question deleted if you don't need it.

Comment: I had the same issue. I can add that before having the same situation I had ran the following: gem install rails -v 3.1.8 (i had rails 3.2.8 installed but I needed rails 3.1 and i heard it's ok to have both). After using it for a while, I decided to uninstall it so I ran: gem cleanup (keeps most updated gems and uninstall older ones).Well after that rails command was not working, reinstalled,same thing. I'm using rvm, so i did "rvm repail all". After that,gem command was not working as well ("not found"). Installing rvm again now (from github)... Fun thing: Github Status: Major service outage.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue after switching to an older version of Rails (3.2.16) from 4.0.2.

In my case it looks like railties need to be uninstalled as well - not just the rails gem.

Here's what I've done:

```
gem uninstall rails # choose to remove all
gem uninstall railties # choose to remove all
gem install rails -v 3.2.16
```

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me after I uninstalled an old version of rails, and it asked me if I wanted to remove the binary too (which I did).

The newer rails binary is hidden under

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/bin/rails
```

(on Ubuntu)

So I just created the symlink (not sure if this has negative side affects but it seems to work):

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/bin/rails /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up using the RVM installer. This post http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/ shows you how and why use this tool.

Answer (score 0):

check that rvm is a function `type rvm | head -1`

Answer (score -1):

Try installing with:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

If you are running RVM you may not have it configured properly.